# Classic asp inline split

Tags: asp-classic, split

How do I split inline in classic asp? Something like this for getting domain:

```
domain=split("mailbox@domain.com").item(1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the split character as second argument to the `Split` function:

```
domain = Split("mailbox@domain.com", "@")(1)
```